# Is blocking main method in Java always bad?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

We have an application that's continuously running. Nothing much goes on in the main method except initializing a few background threads. The background threads process socket events as they occur. Apart from the time the socket events are being processed, app remains in the idle state.

Main

- Start Thread 1 -> while(socket connection 1 is good) -> process events
- Start Thread 2 -> while(socket connection 2 is good) -> process events
- Start Thread 3 -> while(socket connection 3 is good) -> process events
- Start Thread 4 -> while(socket connection 4 is good) -> process events

```
while (true); // block main thread from exiting. Otherwise, periodic GC calls kills the app.
```

As the primary function of my app is to process events and there is not foreground tasks as such. Does blocking main thread is bad in my case? What are some other alternates?

Comment: `while (true);` is the worst possible way of blocking a thread. Use `Thread.sleep()` in your loop at least.

Comment: I would not use busy waiting, but a synchronization method (e.g. [`Thread::join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join())). Otherwise, there is nothing "special" about the main thread, except, maybe, that the runtime is teared down when the main thread terminates.

Comment: The runtime is not teared down when the main thread terminates. The JVM exits when the last non-daemon thread terminates. Whether or not this thread is the main thread. What I don't really guess (there is no code!) is why you want to keep running if all threads are done and will never do anything else.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, that is true =) I was just too lazy to type it out. In a fully-fledged answer, It would have been a footnote =)

Comment: Re, "...Otherwise, periodic GC calls kills the app." What is the basis for that comment? The main thread in a Java program (unlike, in C++) is no more special than any other thread. A Java program only terminates after _all_ of its non-daemon threads have terminated. If the main thread exits early, other threads can continue to run, and nothing should be "collected" as a result of main disappearing except for objects that could not possibly have been used by any of the other threads.

Comment: To avoid any major design change at the moment I replaced it with Thread.currentThread().join() It serves the purpose. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your main thread does busy waiting it will require thread scheduler to it (main thread) into list of scheduled threads. And if your machine where you are running your app has less then 4 CPUs then your event processing threads will suffer.

There are a lot of other ways to block your main thread without busy waiting. `Thread.join()` as mentioned above is one of them. You can also use `Future.get()`, or `ExecutorService.awaitTermination()` if you use high level concurrency objects.

Comment: OP asked if blocking the main method is a bad idea. The presented attempt would block aswell.

Comment: @Turing85 those options will not block main thread forever like the one in question. Main thread need to wait until other threads do their work anyway, if I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 2):

the main thread is just the first thread, and as such is not different from any other thread. If you block it, it means waste of memory occupied by this thread (about 1MB) and nothing more. So I would just return from the main method, if there is no job for this thread.

I noticed a comment in your code: *block main thread from exiting. Otherwise, periodic GC calls kills the app*. The comment is wrong. GC calls cannot kill the application. I suspect other threads are started in daemon mode, and so the enclosing process does not wait for them to finish.

If you describe in more details when the whole process must end, we could make more sensible advises.

Comment: I have a Helper object initialized from the Main() method. The helper class spawns worker threads and maintains them. I noticed after every 1 hr Helper object was getting finalized by GC. On finalize I have some cleanup code to interrupt threads and close socket connections. Now I am holding on to main thread so worker thread can complete. So I don't see the helper object being finalized anymore. It resolves the problem i was facing. However, I am going to re-design this app to avoid such issues.

Comment: @Nova to prevent an object to be garbage collected, you need a reference to it from a non-daemon thread. This can be main thread, or a worker thread.

Comment: I have a reference to the helper object from the main thread. Without thread.join call the main threads finishes quickly while the worker threads are doing their work. As the main thread is done, no one is holding on to the helper object anymore, so it gets finalized in next GC cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a bad design. Use a ExecutorService and add the threads to it.

Comment: OP asked if blocking the main method is a bad idea. The presented attempt would block aswell.

Comment: @Turing85 Sure, but the answer is "No, unless you do wrong (e.g., like you did)". Correct, but not helpful. A helpful answer provides some solution, no matter if blocking the main thread or not.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking in the main method (or from any other thread) should be avoided. The problem you are running into – how to create some threads and keep the JVM running until those threads finish – can be solved in better ways.

If you create a new [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and call [setDaemon(false)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-), then you won't need to do anything with sleeping or waiting. By setting the thread to be non-daemon, the JVM will stay running until that thread completes. From the Javadoc:

> The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.

Here's an example thread class that tries to sleep for 2 seconds, then prints out a message:

```
class ExampleThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("done sleeping");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you call it like this – by setting daemon to false – you will first see 
output `thread started`, followed by 2 seconds of nothing, then output `done sleeping`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExampleThread t = new ExampleThread();
    t.setDaemon(false);
    t.start();

    System.out.println("thread started");
}
```

If you replace `t.setDaemon(false)` with this `t.setDaemon(true)` – so that the new thread is in fact a daemon thread – then you will see output `thread started` followed by immediate JVM termination.

Comment: The `t.setDaemon(false)` call should have no effect.  The "daemonness" of a new thread is the same as the the thread that created it by default, and the main() thread is not a daemon thread.

Comment: In this example, yes, it is not necessary to call `setDaemon(false)` because the creating thread is also false and the new thread should inherit that. But OP's scenario must be doing something different such that the threads end up with "daemon true", which led to attempts to keep the main thread alive indefinitely with `while (true);`. So my example is explicit about making the call – `setDaemon(false)` – to make it clear how to get the correct result.